# Getting specific values from ASCII table

Tags: python, ascii, genetic-algorithm

I'm currently creating a genetic algorithm and am trying to only get certain values from the ASCII table so the runtime of the algorithm can be a bit faster. In the code below I get the values between 9-127 but I only need the values 9-10, and 32-127 from the ASCII table and I'm not sure on how to exactly only get those specific values. Code below is done in python.

```
import numpy as np

TARGET_PHRASE = """The smartest and fastest Pixel yet.

Google Tensor: Our first custom-built processor.
The first processor designed by Google and made for Pixel, Tensor makes the new Pixel phones our most powerful yet.

The most advanced Pixel Camera ever.
Capture brilliant color and vivid detail with Pixels best-in-class computational photography and new pro-level lenses."""       # target DNA
POP_SIZE = 4000                      # population size
CROSS_RATE = 0.8                    # mating probability (DNA crossover)
MUTATION_RATE = 0.00001                # mutation probability
N_GENERATIONS = 100000

DNA_SIZE = len(TARGET_PHRASE)
TARGET_ASCII = np.fromstring(TARGET_PHRASE, dtype=np.uint8)  # convert string to number
ASCII_BOUND = [9, 127]


class GA(object):
    def __init__(self, DNA_size, DNA_bound, cross_rate, mutation_rate, pop_size):
        self.DNA_size = DNA_size
        DNA_bound[1] += 1
        self.DNA_bound = DNA_bound
        self.cross_rate = cross_rate
        self.mutate_rate = mutation_rate
        self.pop_size = pop_size

        self.pop = np.random.randint(*DNA_bound, size=(pop_size, DNA_size)).astype(np.int8)  # int8 for convert to ASCII

    def translateDNA(self, DNA):                 # convert to readable string
        return DNA.tostring().decode('ascii')

    def get_fitness(self):                      # count how many character matches
        match_count = (self.pop == TARGET_ASCII).sum(axis=1)
        return match_count

    def select(self):
        fitness = self.get_fitness()     # add a small amount to avoid all zero fitness
        idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(self.pop_size), size=self.pop_size, replace=True, p=fitness/fitness.sum())
        return self.pop[idx]

    def crossover(self, parent, pop):
        if np.random.rand() < self.cross_rate:
            i_ = np.random.randint(0, self.pop_size, size=1)                        # select another individual from pop
            cross_points = np.random.randint(0, 2, self.DNA_size).astype(np.bool)   # choose crossover points
            parent[cross_points] = pop[i_, cross_points]                            # mating and produce one child
        return parent

    def mutate(self, child):
        for point in range(self.DNA_size):
            if np.random.rand() < self.mutate_rate:
                child[point] = np.random.randint(*self.DNA_bound)  # choose a random ASCII index
        return child

    def evolve(self):
        pop = self.select()
        pop_copy = pop.copy()
        for parent in pop:  # for every parent
            child = self.crossover(parent, pop_copy)
            child = self.mutate(child)
            parent[:] = child
        self.pop = pop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ga = GA(DNA_size=DNA_SIZE, DNA_bound=ASCII_BOUND, cross_rate=CROSS_RATE,
            mutation_rate=MUTATION_RATE, pop_size=POP_SIZE)

    for generation in range(N_GENERATIONS):
        fitness = ga.get_fitness()
        best_DNA = ga.pop[np.argmax(fitness)]
        best_phrase = ga.translateDNA(best_DNA)
        print('Gen', generation, ': ', best_phrase)
        if best_phrase == TARGET_PHRASE:
            break
        ga.evolve()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a customed method to generate random samples in range 9-10, and 32-127, like

```
def my_rand(pop_size, DNA_size):
    bold1=[9,10]
    bold2=list(range(32,127))
    bold=bold1+bold2
    pop = np.random.choice(bold,(pop_size,DNA_size)).astype(np.int8)
    return pop
```

then call this method to replace the line 29, like

```
delete -- self.pop = np.random.randint(*DNA_bound, size=(pop_size, DNA_size)).astype(np.int8)  # int8 for convert to ASCII
call ---self.pop = my_rand(pop_size, DNA_size)
```